# A key in JSON response sometimes Int and sometimes comes as String

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

How to parse when data type of key is random sometimes comes as Int/string. Below is my code what have tried so far but not working:

```
  do {
       // let value = try String(container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .Quantity))
          let value = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .Quantity)
          Quantity = value == 0 ? nil : String(value)
      } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
        Quantity = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .Quantity)
      }
```

Thanks

Comment: @Timmy I already gone through this post and checked the accepted answer but it's not working in this case. Same code I have mention in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the type of data may change, you can simply try parsing the data with a different type, as follows:

```swift
if let intValue = try? container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .Quantity) {
    // The integer value here
} else if stringValue = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .Quantity) {
    // The string value here
}
```

You can also use the `do-catch` to handle parsing errors like this:

```
do {
    let intValue = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .Quantity)
} catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
    let stringValue = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .Quantity)
} catch {
    // Handle an error here
}
```